# Tailwind UI components aren't renderring correctly in Next.js?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I followed the Tailwind UI [getting started documentation](https://tailwindui.com/documentation), but for some reason it looks nothing like it's supposed to in my Next.js project.

Here is my tailwind.config.ts:

```
export const defaultTheme = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme");

module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ["Inter var", ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/forms")],
};
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nextjs-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.5.0",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.6",
    "next": "12.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "17.0.21",
    "@types/react": "17.0.40",
    "eslint": "8.11.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.6.2"
  }
}
```

Here's my `_document.tsx`:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&display=optional"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

Here is what the Signin component looks like:

[image: What it looks like]

Here's what it should look like:

[image: What it should look like]

Answer (score 0):

Add your extra file paths (such as 'components' and 'sections') to `tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    // ADD extra paths here...
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

As shown here - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs